# C global unsized array?

Tags: c, arrays, linked-list

We had a school project, any information system using C. To keep a dynamic-sized list of student records, I went for a linked list data structure. This morning my friend let me see his system. I was surprised with his list of records:

```
#include <stdio.h>
/* and the rest of the includes */

/* global unsized array */
int array[];

int main()
{
    int n;
    for (n=0; n < 5; n ++) {
         array[n] = n;
    }


    for (n=0; n < 5; n ++) {
         printf("array[%d] = %d\n", n, array[n]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

As with the code, he declared an unsized array that is global (in the bss segment) to the whole program. He was able to add new entries to the array by overwriting subsequent blocks of memory with a value other than zero so that he can traverse the array thusly:

```
for (n=0; array[n]; n++) {
    /* do something */
}
```

He used (I also tested it with) Turbo C v1. I tried it in linux and it also works.

As I never encountered this technique before, I am presuming there is a problem with it. So, yeah, I wanna know why this is a bad idea and why prefer this over a linked list.

Comment: It's the same as writing to any out of bounds array - undefined.

Comment: is this supposed to be c99?

Comment: 1der Please check update answer of teppic's. and open the codepad link you can observe the undefined behavior of C in your code.

Answer (score 7):

```
int array[];
```

Is technically known as an **array with incomplete type**. Simply put it is equivalent to:

```
int array[1];
```

This is not good simply because:

1. It produces an **Undefined behavior**. The primary use of array with incomplete type is in **[Struct Hack](http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=cplusplus&seqNum=288)**. Note that incomplete array types where standardized in C99 and they are illegal before.

Comment: Isn't it just UB, because GCC says `source.c:4:5: warning: array 'array' assumed to have one element [enabled by default]` which would mean he'd write outside the bounds of the array going any further then 1 element?

Comment: It's not a VLA, it's just writing to a random address in memory.

Comment: Hi Is it really `int array[];` `==` `int array[1];` **?** give me the link to read..

Answer (score 4):

This is **Undefined behaviour**. You are writing to unallocated memory (beyond the array). In order to compile this, the compiler is allocating at least one element, and you're then writing beyond that. Try a much bigger range of numbers. For example, if I run your code on Linux it works, but if I change the loop to 50,000, it crashes.

**EDIT** The code may work for small values of `n` but for larger values it will fail. To demonstrate this I've written your code and tested it for `n = 1000`.

Here is the link for [**CODEPAD**](http://codepad.org/OhHm2W73), and you can see that for n = 1000, a **segmentation fault** happens.

Whereas with the same code with the same compiler, it is working for n = 10, see this link [CODEPAD](http://codepad.org/XejRMejG). So this is called **Undefined behavior**.

Comment: I add some more detail in your answer to demonstrate Undefined behavior for code. Hope you like it. If not you can revert back to your version

Answer (score 0):

If you use linked lists you can check whether the memory is allocated properly or not.

```
int *ptr;
ptr = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int))
if(ptr==NULL)
{
  printf("No Memory!!!");
}
```

But with your code the program simply crashes if tested with an array having a large bound.